# MySQL increase the old value by the new value when inserting new records by "on duplicate key update"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I've created a new table like this:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| first      | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| last       | varchar(400) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| source     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| count      | int          | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I try to insert multiple records to this table using this:

```
insert into my_table(first,last,source,count) values ('a','b','c',50),('a','b','c',20),('d','e','f',30) on duplicate key update count = count + 1;
```

After insert, this is the content of the table:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| first      | last      | source | count |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| a          | b         | c      |     2 |
| d          | e         | f      |     1 |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

However, I'd like the count to be updated by the numbers provided in the values of the new records (i.e., 50, 20, and 30 in the provided example). So, the table should look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| first      | last      | source | count |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| a          | b         | c      |    70 |
| d          | e         | f      |    30 |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this using "on duplicate key update" in MySQL? Or is there any other efficient way to achieve this? The table will be very large (with millions of rows).

Comment: I don't know what you are using this for, but to me this raises some caution flags. You may be better off removing the unique index and instead just run a query to sum() the count column and group it by the columns in the unique index instead. With the way you have it now something could be added twice and it would be difficult to identify and fix unless you have a record of it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `VALUES()` syntax, that you can use in the `on duplicate key`  clause to refer to the column value that would otherwise have been inserted:

```
insert into my_table(first, last, source, count) 
values ('a','b','c',50), ('a','b','c',20), ('d','e','f',30) 
on duplicate key update count = count + VALUES(count);
```

Note: `first`, `last` and `source` are [MySQL keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). I would not recommend using them as column names.

Comment: How to achieve this when I'm using select as a source of data?

Answer (score 2):

`VALUES()` is the method to use, as GMB mentioned, if you are on a mysql version older than 8.0.19. However, it was deprecated as of 8.0.20, if you are using mysql 8.0.19 or newer its recommended to give an alias to the rows being inserted, and then refer to the values of the inserts by the alias like this:

```
insert into my_table (first, last, source, count) 
values ('a','b','c',50), ('a','b','c',20), ('d','e','f',30) as newRow
on duplicate key update count = count + newRow.count;
```

More information can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html